# Convert 'key' to a super parameter warning -- how to change existing super calls to use super named parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class FooPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooPage(Key? key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FooPage> createState() => _FooPageState();
}
```

Is there any `dart fix xyz` command I can use to convert all the `super(key:key)` calls to `super.key`?

In other words:

##### Before:

```dart
const FooPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

##### After:

```dart
const FooPage({super.key});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this linter rule to your `analysis_options.yaml` file:

```
linter:
  rules:
    use_super_parameters: true
```

Now run

```
dart fix --apply --code use_super_parameters
```